# Is it possible to rezise the graph dots in the jquery library flot when being hovered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flot

when working with the jquery library flot ([like this](http://jsfiddle.net/VpGnS/49/)), you might want increase precision when hovering over he dots, so my question is if there is any way of making this area of whitin a dot is hovarable bigger?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `radius` property of the `series` hash you pass to the `$.plot` function to set the radius of the clickable data point on the chart. So instead of this as it is now:

```
points: { show: true }
```

change it to, say, this:

```
points: { show: true, radius: 6 }
```

The measurement is in pixels and the default radius is 3 pixels. Personally speaking I wouldn't go much above that if the data points are close together like in the example chart: you run into the opposite problem where all the points overlap and run into each other.

Comment: That's almost the answer to my question, what your suggestion does is that it enlarges the button both when hovered and not hovered, but what I'm asking for is that the area of whitin a button is hoverable in is enlarged, not the button itself. Is that possible? =)

Comment: I'm confused. This is what I think you mean: keep the button *visibly* the same size, but make the *invisible* "hit area" larger. If not, you'll have to explain in a different way, because I'm not getting it.